# How to combine multiple charts created using JFreeChart API?

Tags: java, jfreechart

My requirement is need to display 2 barchart and 3 trendchart in single page. For that, i have used JFreeChart API and sending the image in bytearray format through response. Its working fine for single image. How do i merge all 5 charts and send that through response?. Please help me.

Sample Code:

```
            chartTypeCode="1";
            chartTypeDesc="Order Line Status Bar Chart";
            chart = createChart(defaultFromDate,defaultToDate,chartTypeCode);
            chartImage[0] = chart.createBufferedImage(600, 400);

            chartTypeCode="2";
            chartTypeDesc="Order Sent To OMS Trend Chart";
            chart = createTrendChart(defaultFromDate,defaultToDate,chartTypeCode);
            chartImage[1] = chart.createBufferedImage(600, 400);

            chartTypeCode="3";
            chartTypeDesc="Shipment Trend Chart";
            chart = createTrendChart(defaultFromDate,defaultToDate,chartTypeCode);
            chartImage[2] = chart.createBufferedImage(600, 400);

            chartTypeCode="4";
            chartTypeDesc="Return Trend Chart";
            chart = createTrendChart(defaultFromDate,defaultToDate,chartTypeCode);
            chartImage[3] = chart.createBufferedImage(600, 400);

            chartTypeCode="5";
            chartTypeDesc="PSP Email Bar Chart";
            chart = createChart(defaultFromDate,defaultToDate,chartTypeCode);
            chartImage[4] = chart.createBufferedImage(600, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can send many charts as they are individual images. 
You should consider instead saving each chart to your server using [servlet utilities](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/servlet/ServletUtilities.html) and then using JFreeChart's [servlet](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/servlet/DisplayChart.html) to query each image. This will allow you to use standard image tags which means you can use text html with maps (for tooltips) and css.

See my answer to a similar question for [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347417/saving-a-png-file-on-a-server-in-a-java-bean-using-jstl/1462961#1462961).