# Blackberry Development - Does JFreeChart work on Blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, jfreechart

Does JFreeChart work on Blackberry?

(Just want to get a quick answer before I spend hours trying to give it a shot, would rather know now if it doesn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as it states on the front page for that library "JFreeChart requires the Java 2 platform (JDK version 1.3 or later)" and the BlackBerry platform is J2ME (CLDC 1.1).

If you can post what requirements you are looking for, perhaps the community can recomand a library that works for you.  For example on of the regular BlackBerry contributors on Stack Overflow works for a company that provides a product called [aiCharts](http://www.artfulbits.com/blackberry/aiCharts.aspx) and I'm guessing there are others out there, too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot if you are looking to run JFreeChart directly on the Blackberry as Marc mentioned. If however you are up for a little web programming then JFreeChart would be on the server which could surely meet the java requirements. JFreeChart can serve up images and html maps for interactive use. Check out another [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347417/saving-a-png-file-on-a-server-in-a-java-bean-using-jstl/1462961#1462961) for tips.